# Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Void?' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Void?' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1MYV.png`func deselectSelectedCells() {
        if let start = startDateIndexPath {
            var section = start.section
            var item = start.item + 1

```
        if let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: start) as? AirbnbDatePickerCell {
            cell.type.remove([.InBetweenDate, .SelectedStartDate, .SelectedEndDate, .Selected])
            cell.configureCell()
            collectionView?.deselectItem(at: start, animated: false)
        }

        if let end = endDateIndexPath {
            var indexPathArr = [IndexPath]()
            while section < months.count, section <= end.section {
                let curIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                if let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: curIndexPath) as? AirbnbDatePickerCell {
                    cell.type.remove([.InBetweenDate, .SelectedStartDate, .SelectedEndDate, .Selected])
                    cell.configureCell()
                    collectionView?.deselectItem(at: curIndexPath, animated: false)
                }

                if section == end.section && item >= end.item {
                    // stop iterating beyond end date
                    break
                } else if item >= (collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 1) {
                    // more than num of days in the month
                    section += 1
                    item = 0
                } else {
                    item += 1
                }
            }

            collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                (s) in
                self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: indexPathArr)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: remove `(s) in`?

Comment: Where possible paste code rather than using screenshots, it makes it easier for someone to try an test your example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the solution. `performBatchUpdates` takes callback without parameter, but you define there a parameter.

Remove line with `(s) in` under `performBatchUpdates` (line 40) that declares a parameter for a callback.

Comment: When am hiding that line I got an another issue, Month is not displayed between the calendars

Comment: I have pasted the code let me have solution for this?